# Is this the correct approach to updating my table based on another table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there [are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/707383/441662) a [bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27154640/441662) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262848/441662) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334741/441662), but some don't work with MySQL and others seem to run infinitely until I kill them manually using the `processlist`, including the one below.

```
-- both tables have around 3.5 million rows
UPDATE A a
INNER JOIN B b ON a.indexed = b.indexed
SET a.B_id = b.id;
```

I guess where I deviated from the other questions is that I don't join on the primary keys (I'm updating those instead), but I don't think that should matter. And around 3.5 million rows (both tables) shouldn't spill over to disk unless perhaps I'm accidentally running a Cartesian product.

So what am I doing wrong?

/edit: query finally finished on the server after about 40 minutes.

Comment: "perhaps I'm accidentally running a Cartesian product." Don't worry your not running a Cartesian product.. You might gain better performance when you make a covering index on B(indexed, id)